# Databricks SDK Cannot Get Run_Job Information (13.3 Spark Version)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, sdk, databricks, databricks-sdk

I have python code that runs from a Notebook and clones our Databricks workflows. It works correctly when using Spark Version 12.2. But when we try to clone our workflows on Spark Version 13.3, it specifically errors on run_job tasks in the workflow missing task details.

Looking further, here is what w.jobs.get() returns from the same job using 13.3 vs 12.2. It can be seen 13.3 returns nothing regarding the underlying run_job information.

`w.jobs.get(999999999999999)`
13.3 Returns:

```
Job(created_time=1703001792570, creator_user_name='<email>', 
job_id=431377762843831, run_as_user_name='<email>', 
settings=JobSettings(continuous=None, 
email_notifications=JobEmailNotifications(no_alert_for_skipped_runs=False, 
on_failure=None, on_start=None, on_success=None), format=<JobSettingsFormat.MULTI_TASK: 
'MULTI_TASK'>, git_source=None, job_clusters=None, max_concurrent_runs=1, name='Test 
Cloner 13.3', schedule=None, tags=None, tasks=
[JobTaskSettings(task_key='test_13_3_cloner', dbt_task=None, depends_on=None, 
description=None, email_notifications=None, existing_cluster_id=None, 
job_cluster_key=None, libraries=None, max_retries=None, min_retry_interval_millis=None, 
new_cluster=None, notebook_task=None, pipeline_task=None, python_wheel_task=None, 
retry_on_timeout=None, spark_jar_task=None, spark_python_task=None, 
spark_submit_task=None, sql_task=None, timeout_seconds=0)], timeout_seconds=0, 
trigger=None, webhook_notifications=None), trigger_history=None)
```

12.2 Returns:

```
Job(created_time=1703001792570, creator_user_name='<email>', job_id=999999999999999, 
run_as_user_name='<email>', settings=JobSettings(compute=None, continuous=None, 
deployment=None, description=None, edit_mode=None, 
email_notifications=JobEmailNotifications(no_alert_for_skipped_runs=False, 
on_duration_warning_threshold_exceeded=None, on_failure=None, on_start=None, 
on_success=None), format=<Format.MULTI_TASK: 'MULTI_TASK'>, git_source=None, health=None, 
job_clusters=None, max_concurrent_runs=1, name='Test Cloner 13.3', 
notification_settings=None, parameters=None, queue=None, run_as=None, schedule=None, 
tags=None, tasks=[Task(task_key='test_13_3_cloner', compute_key=None, 
condition_task=None, dbt_task=None, depends_on=None, description=None, 
email_notifications=None, existing_cluster_id=None, health=None, job_cluster_key=None, 
libraries=None, max_retries=None, min_retry_interval_millis=None, new_cluster=None, 
notebook_task=None, notification_settings=None, pipeline_task=None, 
python_wheel_task=None, retry_on_timeout=None, run_if=<RunIf.ALL_SUCCESS: 'ALL_SUCCESS'>, 
run_job_task=RunJobTask(job_id=888888888888888, job_parameters=None), 
spark_jar_task=None, spark_python_task=None, spark_submit_task=None, sql_task=None, 
timeout_seconds=0, webhook_notifications=None)], timeout_seconds=0, trigger=None, 
webhook_notifications=None), trigger_history=None)
```

What should I be doing to get() the same type of job contents with this cloner notebook running spark version 13.3?